# React native build error: Unexpected > token punc «:», expected punc «,» in file

Tags: react-native

Hitting this error when building for react native 0.62.2.

> error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/URL.js: Unexpected
> token punc «:», expected punc «,» in file
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/URL.js at 104:30. Run CLI
> with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Unexpected token punc
> «:», expected punc «,» in file
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/URL.js at 104:30

Tried removing node_modules and yarn.lock, but to no avail. :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Issue is due to metro-react-native-babel-preset. update it to "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2"

Comment: Thanks @Ashok Vijayendra. It works! weird thing is i'm already using ^0.58.0 in package.json file. Shouldn't the carat sign upgrade it from 0.58 to to 0.66 automatically (assuming i don't have a yarn.lock file and node_modules are removed prior to running "yarn" command)

Comment: It would. But if you look at the package-lock.json you would see multiple versions of metro-react-native-babel-preset which results in lowest version of metro-react-native-babel-preset getting installed.

Comment: does this have any unwanted consequences? e.g. should you update the react-native version as well?

Comment: No, it would *not* take 0.66 automatically if you specify `^0.58.0`. That's because according to semver, if you are on a "0.x" version range (major version 0), the caret *only updates the patch component, not minor* (e.g. it would only update to `0.58.1`). This is a different behavior compared to major versions 1 and higher.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer by Ashok provides a solution that works.

If you are interested in more details, as well as alternative ways to fix it, please read on.

Upgrading to the latest version of `metro-react-native-babel-preset` is **not necessary**. It could potentially lead to other other compatibility problems. The error was fixed in 0.59, which first shipped with React Native 0.63. If you are using an older version of React Native, it is possible that you are still locked to a version <0.59.

**Option 1** Upgrade `metro-react-native-babel-preset` at least to `0.59`:

```
yarn add -D metro-react-native-babel-preset@^0.59
```

Now to the additional details and root cause of this build error. The origins can be traced back to the release of [Babel 7.16.8](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.16.8) on January 10, 2022. This StackOverflow question was created the following day, Jan 11. `@babel/traverse@7.16.8` includes the following PR:

https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/14105

This PR fixes a bug in the way Babel traverses the AST. The fix was not expected to have any adverse impact (as can be seen by the fact that only the patch version was increased). However, versions of `metro-react-native-babel-preset` prior to 0.59 internally relied on this bug to exist.

Why did this suddenly break? Because `metro-react-native-babel-preset` declares all babel dependencies as `^7.0.0` (meaning: Take any minor and patch release in the 7.x major version series). Normally, a dependency lock file in an application project should avoid any unexpected dependency changes, but in some cases, dependency locks are not available (or used).

Two alternative fixes for the issue **without** updating `metro-react-native-babel-preset`:

**Option 2** (when using version `0.58.0` of `metro-react-native-babel-preset`)

Change the following line in `babel.config.js` from

```
presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
```

to

```
presets: [['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', {
  unstable_disableES6Transforms: true
}]],
```

**Option 3** (for earlier versions of `metro-react-native-babel-preset`)

Add the following to `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/traverse": "7.16.7"
  }
```

These options were described in detail by kerm1it and others in the following issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14139

Another amazingly detailed reply by Nicolò Ribaudo regarding a related bug in docz can be found here:

https://github.com/doczjs/docz/issues/1691#issuecomment-1025928444

Comment: This answer's **Option 2** worked for me.

Comment: Option 1 worked

Comment: Comprehensive, well-structured answer with a resolution for me which was Option 3. Kudos Frieder!

Comment: Option 3 worked perfectly to fix the build of an older app running `react-native` 0.59.5 / `metro-react-native-babel-preset` 0.53.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any of the solutions listed should work, but it's worth noting that you should probably run `npx react-native start --reset-cache` to clear the transform cache. [image: npx react-native start --reset-cache]

Answer (score -1):

Check your directory before running the command. You have to be in root directory of the project.